Kafka send compatibility in different environments
A question about using libraries builded in spring boot 3 environment.
I have a librirary/service that sends a message to kafka which made in the spring-boot 3  with spring-kafka-3.1.6
So I am trying to run this service in spring boot 2 with spring-kafka-2.8.11 lib in classpath.
Service looks like:
var message = new GenericMessage<>(bodyMessage,
        Map.of("kafka_messageKey", keyId());
kafkaTemplate.send(message).get();

kafkaTemplate.send

spring-kafka-3.1.6 return CompletableFuture
spring-kafka-2.8.11 return ListenableFuture

Both versions implementing Future and have method get() which I call to block to get answer.
But then it run with spring-boot 2
kafkaTemplate.send(message)

I get exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(org.springframework.messaging.Message)

Why it happens?
If I stop in debug point and evaluate expression in intellijIdea it executed without exception.
